# Using observableArray element in if condition

Tags: knockout.js

I am using the ko `if` statement in my html view, which refers to a knockout observableArray.

You can see [my code on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mang/pyh9m7de/).

I am curious why this line of code is not working?

```html
<!-- ko if: numbers()[1].value > 1 -->
```

If I print out the `value`, I am getting the value that I expected.

Comment: It should be <!-- ko if: numbers()[1].value() > 1 -->

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be `<!-- ko if: numbers()[1].value() > 1 -->`
since `numbers()[1].value` is an *observable* (every observable is a function).

In the above case when `if: numbers()[1].value > 1` is considered, you are comparing a function with 1 (which is always false).

Answer (score 1):

You should use brackets after "value", because the "value" is an observable and you want to use its content:

```
<!-- ko if: numbers()[1].value() > 1 -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way

```
<h4>Numbers</h4>
<button data-bind="click: add">Add</button>
 <input id="myid" data-bind="value: numbers()[1].value"></input>
 <!-- ko foreach: numbers -->    
<!-- ko if: $index() == 1-->
<div data-bind="text: value">
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
<!--/ko-->
<span data-bind="text: sum"></span>
```